# How to use domain jar with persistence.xml as a library in EAR to deploy on WebLogic?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, weblogic

I am using a domain library from external system. The domain library has also persistence.xml in META/INF folder. And also i put that library in lib directory of my EAR file. But when i try to deploy my EAR application it files that the datasource defined in persistence.xml not found which is correct. But i don't need that datasource, the only think i need are class files in the library. How can i use the jar as a library only?

The exception that is thrown by WebLogic as follows:

```
  ####<2014-03-04 14:25:27 ALMT> <Error> <Deployer> <EPKZKARW0321> <server2> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1393921527172> <WL-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1393921501134" for task "43". Error is: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'comp.env.jdbc.MyDS'. Resolved 'comp.env.jdbc'; remaining name 'MyDS'"
  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'comp.env.jdbc.MyDS'. Resolved 'comp.env.jdbc'; remaining name 'MyDS'
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:250)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:406)
```

Comment: Why not open the EAR file and remove that datasource? That said, weblogic does have an option to deploy as a library instead of an application: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/deploy.html#1020594

Comment: Well, of course it can and i did remove that persistence.xml file as a workaround. But would like to know how to deploy it as library with EAR file itself without deploying it as a separate library.